# Need a common object between httpcontext and httpcontextbase

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using both asp.net mvc 5 and asp.net web api 2 owin based web application.
The first one is the website and the second one is the backend api.

I need to share some libraries, 
in the asp.net mvc application i can access to HttpContextBase.Request that is a HttpBaseRequest
in the web.api a can access to httpContext.Request that is a HttpRequest

Planning to upgrade to asp.net core in future, what is the best way to have a common object to share in my class libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an interface representing access to httpcontext, however without binding it to any specific http-related type

Then, provide implementations specific to frameworks that your libraries and apps are dealing with. .net framework and .net mvc and dotnet-core each define different implementations for http contexf, request, response.

e.g.

```
interface IMyHttpContext

class Net4HttpContext : IMyHttpContext

class NetCoreHttpContext : IMyHttpContext
```

then, expose just what you need. e.g. GetRequestPath, WriteToResponse, GetHeader, SetCookie. etc..It'll be a lot of and ongoing work, but as a result, your netstandard libraries (one of which should host your interface, btw) won't care about the impementation. Obviously, you'll have to replace all usages of specific http objects to your interface.

So, IMyHttpContext goes to one new netstandard assembly..This assembly will work with all dotnet frameworks.

Net4HttpContext goes to net45 assembly, itself referencing System.Webb. you reference this one by windows-only, .net framework apps.

NetCoreHttpContext goes to dotnetcore or netstandard assembly, referencing dotnet core's http-related nuget packages. use this one with dotnet core apps.

Then, throughout your apps, whether they are net45 or netcore, along with some DI setup, you reference just your interface. Implementations get to be injected.

Good luck.